# how to type python API responses similar to TS `as`?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I'm using a lib that types its response as

`-> (Unknown | Response | Any)`

If i know/expect the response to be a `Response` and that is has an `id` field,
how can I cast that in my code?

Typescript provides an `as <type>` operator for this.

```
        response = self.client.get_user(username=username)
        user_id = response.data['id']
```

```
Cannot access member "data" for type "Response"
  Member "data" is unknownPylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
```

in addition to the `typing.cast` I'm looking for a simple way to define the shape of a response, without adding a full class hierarchy just to type a blob of data coming back from a third party API.
Similar to `type` or even `interface` in typescript.

It seems the Response object/class isn't typed.

[image]

Comment: update: Response was imported from the wrong place, works when corrected.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness here, "similar to interface in typescript" are `typing.TypedDict` (dictionary with known keys) and `typing.Protocol` (structural subtyping).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`typing.cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast)

```
response = cast(Response, self.client.get_user(username=username))
user_id = response.data['id']
```